# Hapi/Joi validation with nested object

Tags: javascript, validation, hapi.js, joi

I have the following validation on one of my routes:

```
payload: {
    keywordGroups: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
        language: Joi.string().required(),
        containsAny: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).default([]).when('containsAll', { is: [], then: Joi.required() }),
        containsAll: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).default([]).when('containsAny', { is: [], then: Joi.required() }),
        notContainsAll: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).default([]),
        notContainsAny: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).default([])
    })).required(),
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that `containsAny` or `containsAll` have to include at least one string. If `containsAny` is empty, `containsAll` should have at least one item. And if `containsAll` is empty, `containsAny` should at least include one item.

But it seems `Joi.when` doesn't really work when it comes to an array of objects.

Comment: Try swapping your is: [] for Joi.array().length(0). the documentation suggests the is condition should be a Joi type.
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhenref-options

Comment: I think you're also creating a circular dependency here. see this thread: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/588

Comment: @Cuthbert I think my main question was on how I could reference those fields correctly, seeing that they're in an array of objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`Joi.alternatives()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v7.2.2/API.md#alternatives) otherwise you will create a circular dependency as described in [this issue](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/588).

In your `is` condition in the `when()`, you need to specify a Joi type instead of just an empty array. This example works:

```
import * as Joi from 'joi';

var arraySchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
    first: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).default([])
        .when('second', {is: Joi.array().length(0), then: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).required().min(1)}),
    second: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).default([])
}));

var altArraySchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
    first: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).default([]),
    second: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).default([])
        .when('first', {is: Joi.array().length(0), then: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).required().min(1)}),
}));

var obj = [
    {
        first: [],
        second: []
    }
];

var finalSchema = Joi.alternatives(arraySchema, altArraySchema);

var result = Joi.validate(obj, finalSchema);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

The variable `obj` will fail the validation because both `first` and `second` are empty. Making either of them non-empty will pass the validation check.