# It is possible to create a doubly linked list with Joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have a Joi schema called directorySchema, and, among others keys, this schema has a key called parentDirectory, which type is also a directorySchema and could be null if the directory is a root/head one, and another key called directories, which type is an array of directorySchemas too. Basically this schema represents a doubly linked list.

Follow the example:

```js
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

const directorySchema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  path: Joi.string().required(),
  size: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
  directories: Joi.array().items(...) // how to reference "directorySchema" here
  parentDirectory: ... // and here?
})

module.exports = directorySchema
```

This image explains the concept of doubly linked list, the box objects represents the directories.

[image: In this image that explains the concept of doubly linked list, the box objects represents the directories.]

I would like to know, is it possible to create a double linked list to validate my objects in Joi?

Comment: I personally don't have much experience with Joi directly, but it sounds like you want to create a Schema in where you have attributes referring to other objects of the same schema. Take a look at this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770804/hapi-joi-validation-with-nested-object) for suggestions on how you could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use joi links:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

const directorySchema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  path: Joi.string().required(),
  size: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
  directories: Joi.array().items(Joi.link("#directory"))
}).id("directory")

module.exports = directorySchema
```

Link to documentation: https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#linkref

Comment: Thank you a lot John!!